# Je pars ________ ma sœur

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Fill in the blank with the correct preposition:

Je pars ________ ma sœur.

Will 'de' be correct? Or will 'avec' be correct?

Comment: You should specify what is the meaning you want to convey. "Avec" is one of the most obvious answers but there can be others.

Answer (score 5):

> Je pars **après** ma sœur
>   Je pars **avant** ma sœur
>   Je pars **avec** ma sœur
>   Je pars **chez** ma sœur
>   Je pars **de chez** ma sœur
>   Je pars **derrière** ma sœur
>   Je pars **devant** ma sœur
>   Je pars **malgré** ma sœur
>   Je pars **pour** ma sœur
>   Je pars **sans** ma sœur
>   Je pars **selon** ma sœur
>   ...

Comment: @toto merci ! :-)

Comment: Y'a pas d'quoi ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Will 'de' be correct? Or will 'avec' be correct?

- "de" would not be correct. It would imply you were somehow on the surface of your sister (not to mention inside her).
- "avec" is correct, meaning you are both leaving (an unidentified place) together.

Answer (score 0):

**avec** means she is leaving with you.

**de** means you are leaving her.

Comment: « Je pars **de** ma sœur » n'a aucun sens en français.

Comment: whoops, est-ce que je peux partir d'un pays? ou généralement d'un endroit?

Comment: Ta sœur n'est ni un pays, ni un endroit !

Comment: On dira plutôt "je pars de chez ma soeur" en français courant.